# Equation of the line passing through the origin and parallel to the planes $x+y+z=-1$ and $x-y+z=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Find a vector equation of the line that passes through the origin and is parallel to the planes $x+y+z=-1, x-y+z=1$

Is the answer $2x-2z=0$? I took the normals of the two planes which are $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, -1, 1)$ and used the cross-product to get the normal of the new plane, which is $(2, 0, -2)$. Since the line passes the origin, I would get $2x-2z=0$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: the given two planes are not parallel, I think it means parallel to the intersection of the two planes. And the rest is correct on your way.

Comment: It is right and the equation of the line should be $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)+t(1,0,-1)=t(1,0,-1).$

Comment: Well, **one** equation of the line **could** be...

Comment: Because the cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to the plane contains them.

Comment: It looks like you have a sign error in your cross product.  The normal vector ought to be $(2, 0, 2)$.  Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: Another thing:  to describe a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you *have to* have $2$ independent linear equations.  The equation $2x + 2z = 0$ which you (essentially) found describes a *plane*.  Only with the additional equation $y = 0$ do you get a *line*.

Comment: @Sue You can accept a answer to mark it as answered. [See](http://math.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct.

Here is a different way to describe the line parallel to the intersection of the two planes.  Just row reduce the corresponding homogeneous system of equations.  (These planes are parallel to your given ones but passing through the origin.)

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x + y + z &= 0 \\
x - y + z &= 0
\end{align}
\right.
$$
As matrices,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\leadsto
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\leadsto
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We have
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x + z &= 0 \\
y &= 0
\end{align}
\right.,
$$
which is (by renaming the free variable $z = t$) equivalent to
$$
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -t \\ 0 \\ t \end{bmatrix} = t \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Youre aproach is right.

The line parallel to both planes or just parallel to the intersection can be found by cross product of normals to planes. ie. $(i+j+k)\times (i-j+k)=(2i-2k)$

Or the direction ratios are$(1,0,1)$ 
So line is $$\vec r=(0+0+0)\pm t(i-k)$$
OR$$x+z=0$$
You see it comes out as a plane $x+0\times y+z=0$ which will pass through line of intersection..See the plot by Wolfram
[image: Plot for x+z from Wolfram]

Comment: So it can still be $x-z=0$? I'm confused as to how the z can be positive

Comment: @Sue This plot was for x+z=0

Comment: @Sue  My pleasure.